# Increasing max_user_connections

Tags: cloudbees

we are running up against the 20 max_user_connections for our Run@CloudDB. We tried swapping to the paid db but it also has the same 20 limit. How do we get that change or get a SUPER privileged account to change it?

Comment: any reason why your application is needing more? 20 is a lot of connections when connection pooling is used

Answer (score 1):

The hosted MySQL service has a limit of 20 - in general 20 is a LOT of connections for an application - connection pooling takes care of the rest. A dedicated MySQL database plan (or something like RDS) may give you the option to use more - but it is better to find the cause of the possible "leak" of connections that just up the limit if at all possible.